# App store submission without arm64

Tags: ios, app-store

I'm about to submit an app to the App Store for the first time. I am using the [Box SDK](https://github.com/box/box-ios-sdk-v2), but it doesn't support arm64. So I went into my project's build settings, and removed "arm64" from "Valid Architectures" (leaving only "armv7 armv7s"). My deployment target is iOS 7.0, and I'm using XCode 5.1.1.

My questions are: is it OK to submit without support for arm64? Will my app get rejected?

Also, even if it's not rejected, will it run on 64bit iPads (iPad Air)? I ask because when I try to run in the "iPad Retina (64-bit)" simulator it won't build.

Thank you!

Comment: You do not need to support arm64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is currently OK to not include arm64 when submitting to the App Store. I expect at some point Apple will require arm64 support.

You can run 32-bit apps on the 64-bit device. This allows all the apps already on the App Store to run on the 64-bit capable devices.

Have you tried turning off Build Active Architecture Only in the project settings and then compile for the 64-bit simulator?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I imagined that 64-bit devices should be able to run the 32-bit apps, but I got confused over the 64-bit simulator not building. I tried turning off Build Active Architecture Only, and that took care of my problem. Thanks again!